# Is there a way to specify the CMake Gradle uses when building an Android NDK project?

Tags: android, android-ndk

The origin of this was the `Failed to find CMake` error. However I know that I can install CMake from android studio, please do not suggest that here.

The question is specifically, can I specify the path to the CMake I want gradle to use when buiding my NDK project? Assuming (naturally) that it is not in the standard location.